# How to download a gzipped file in R without saving it to the computer

Tags: r, gzip

I am a new user of R.

I have some txt.gz files on the web of approximate size 9x500000.
I'm trying to uncompress a file and read it straight to R with read.table().
I have used this code (url censored):

```
LoadData <- function(){

con <- gzcon(url("http://"))           
raw <- textConnection(readLines(con, n = 25000))
close(con)
dat <- read.table(raw,skip = 2, na.strings = "99.9")
close(raw)

return(dat)

}
```

The problem is that if I read more lines with readLines, the
program will take much more time to do what it should.

How can I do this is reasonable time?

Comment: Use `system(...)` with appropriate calls to your (unstated) OS's utility facilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't do this.**

Each time you want to access the file, you'll have to re-download it, which is both time consuming for you and costly for the file hoster.

It is better practise to download the file (see `download.file`) and then read in a local copy in a separate step.

You can decompress the file with `untar(..., compressed = "gzip")`.

Comment: OK, got confused by connections. The untar(..., compressed = "gzip")

Comment: seems to give a error message "This does not look like a tar archive" I'm pretty sure it should...

Comment: Since I don't have access to the file that you've downloaded, I can't give much help.  Try opening the file with another program (like 7zip) to check that it hasn't been corrupted.

Comment: Seems like I could read the file straight with read.table() -function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a temporary file like this:

```
tmpfile <- tempfile(tmpdir=getwd()) 
file.create(tmpfile)
download.file(url,tmpfile)
#do your stuff
file.remove(tmpfile)  #delete the tmpfile
```